# Faking an "Undelivered mail" message in Gmail

Tags: chrome, email, gmail

I am looking for a browser extension (preferably Chrome) or web-app that can add some option in the Gmail interface that allows me to reply to an e-mail I received with a standard "Undelivered mail" message in Gmail like:

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <mailer-daemon@googlemail.com>
Date: Sat, Jun 21, 2014 at 12:38 PM
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
To: franck@gmail.com


Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     nonexistantemail@gmail.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596

----- Original message -----

Return-Path: <franck@gmail.com>
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of franck@gmail.com designates 10.112.155.114 as permitted sender) client-ip=10.142.115.103
Authentication-Results: mr.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of franck@gmail.com designates 10.112.155.103 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=franck@gmail.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com
X-Received: from mr.google.com ([10.112.115.103])
        by 10.112.115.103 with SMTP id vv7mr11097164bb.62.1403368684729 (num_hops = 1);
        Sat, 21 Jun 2014 09:38:04 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to:content-type;
        bh=YTpCN1cCqvYms6FGGseMsXBTOhXjUTLSCWhTa7uk91I=;
        b=ABlpZthL6jPX713Aum0fkmVeKiGKDl20ZrfeHylew+L+mSGZSr67J5MLgpoeFvW8lb
         Qb+lyvuZKf3CbDrUTrQ9lIMsDsaBNwvMDS2/s1b3zy2p9sD4l45rwuvN5hSq4vfgYF5R
         izLwOJD5umQvx4CQFeyDsFhhfP7cFQX25YZKP/1x94bjBMI8qL22Bg9Eydvnm4LNPSuu
         xRl9Oo9rO8kLMobxkkIhCKaPGMAkuO7tzaU40tphtWxbyOxwoCGBA/kYi76yjRs142ru
         Sb1fFRF+h2RhgrEXeS4Yvb0qOqJyuyEbGBNgH5wnlRSZBvgGOCLaGvkq8FC3ohu91bE1
         FHKA==
X-Received: by 10.112.141.103 with SMTP id vv9mr1199716lbb.62.1403368684724;
 Sat, 21 Jun 2014 09:38:04 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.112.89.100 with HTTP; Sat, 21 Jun 2014 09:37:44 -0700 (PDT)
From: Franck Dernoncourt <franck@gmail.com>
Date: Sat, 21 Jun 2014 12:37:44 -0400
Message-ID: <CA+e8+riJKFVsGAxv1aaR+LLoDeK8Tx5cZRvQZ=GnrkMNy-SvJA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test
To: nonexistantemail@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=089e01160caef1279604fc5b3b1c

Hi,
spam spam spam
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. If you want to automate this, I can't recommend [google apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) enough(I can help more indepth with that if needed but that's more suited with the [google apps script SO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)). If you wanted something like boomerang where you have an extra button next to all the normal gmail buttons, I think that's done by an extension and I would look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689905/gmail-extension-gadget-api-how-to-add-a-button-to-the-compose-toolbar but this seems inherently more complicated...I think a less involved way(it depends on how much you have invested in a solution and how well you can program) would be to make a bookmarklet or a simple chrome extension that doesn't add a button but opens a new window to make a new email ON CLICK not automatically.

**What I've Found So Far**

If you want to go the bookmarklet route I think `document.querySelectorAll(".gs")[1].children[5].children[0].innerText` gets the innerText of the message, then it'd be simple javascript [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) functions to extract the email out of it. Then, window.open that link prefixed by `"mailto:"`. 
I.E. let's assume you get the email down to variable `email`. Then `window.open("mailto:"+email)` should open your default mail client. Personally, since you wanted to click a button in gmail, you might as well do a bookmarklet

**P.S.**

The only part of this that is variable is that `querySelectorAll` part because if gmail changes much of its internal layout, it will break. I don't have a good answer except play around with the chrome development tools until you find a path